# Why does this buck boost with dual MOSFETs fails output at certain input voltages at light load?

Tags: mosfet, pcb-design, texas-instruments, dual, buck-boost

## Buck boost design

A buck boost converter for 11A 45V output and 33.0-55.0V input has been designed using the [Webench Power Designer](https://webench.ti.com/webench5/power/webench5.cgi?origin=ti_panel&lang_chosen=en_US&VinMin=33&VinMax=55&O1V=45&O1I=11&op_TA=30). The LM5176 based PCB design was adapted for dual MOSFETs (4 times 2 pieces) having the TI evaluation board [SNVU547](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snvu547/snvu547.pdf) in mind.

### Wrong output at light loads

I measured at different input voltages in steps of 1.00V difference.

#### 3.00A output = OK

No output errors were found at steps of 1.00V. Should I repeat with smaller steps?

#### 1.0A output, output error at 46.00V input

It light loads of 1.00A the output is around 15 volts instead of 45 volts.

#### 0.10A output, output error at 42.00, 43.00, 45.00 and 46.00V input

At even lighter loads of 0.100A the output voltage is around 32-40 VDC for 42, 43, 45, and 46 VDC input tests.

As soon as there is an issue, I do hear a "ticking" sound.

### Single MOSFET = OK

I also have the same PCB populated with single (4 times 1) MOSFETs. That board has no issues. I even stepped that board in 0.1V steps over the full range and in 0.01V steps over the 46 to 42 VDC range without spotting any output issues at light 0.100A load.

What is the issue with the (design of the) dual MOSFET board?

---

### Schematic

[image: LM5176 Webench schematic]

### Evaluation board

[image: LM5176 evaluation board bottom side]
[image: LM5176 evaluation board top side]

### Prototype

The prototype is a 6-layer 4Oz printed circuit, where board top and bottom sides of the dual MOSFET version do look like this:
[image: Prototype LM5176 dual MOSFET top side]
[image: Prototype LM5176 dual MOSFET bottom side]

### BOM

- `Rvisns` 1.98kΩ ERJ-6ENF1961V
- `Cboot1`,`Cboot2` 100nF ESR=1mΩ C0603C104M3VACTU
- `Cbulk` 68uF ESR=320mΩ EEV-FK1K680Q
- `Ccomp` 39nF C0603C393K5RACTU
- `Ccomp2` 750pF C0603C751J5GACTU
- `Ccs` 47pF ESR=147mΩ 06035A470JAT2A
- `Cf` 100nF 06035D104KAT2A
- `Cin1`, `Cin2` 15uF ESR=40mΩ 100V 100SXV15M
- `Cin3`…`Cin14`, `Cout1`…`Cout15` 4.7uF ESR=4.236mΩ 100V CGA6M3X7S2A475K200AB
- `Cout16`…`Cout18` 33uF ESR=25mΩ 63V 63SXV33M
- `Cslope` 1.2nF CL10C122JB8NNNC
- `Css` 22nF C0G GCM21B5C1H223JA16L
- `Cvcc` 1uF GRM188R61C105KA93D
- `Dboot1` 10A 0.91V MBRD10200CT-13
- `Dboot2` 20A 100V 0.455V STPS20M100SG-TR
- `Df` 100V 1.0A 1.05V STPS1H100A
- `L1` 10uH SER2915H-103KL
- `M1`,`M3` 80V  BSC037N08NS5ATMA1
- `M2` 150V 50A BSC190N15NS3GATMA1
- `M4` 100V 5.3mΩ CSD19531Q5A
- `Rcomp` 4.64kΩ ERJP03F4641V
- `Rcsg`,`Rcsp` 100Ω
- `Rf` 10Ω
- `Rfbb` 20kΩ
- `Rfbt` 1.1MΩ
- `Rpg` 10kΩ
- `Rt` 86.6kΩ
- `Ruvb` 9.31kΩ
- `Ruvt` 249kΩ
- `Rmode` 93.1kΩ
- `Rsense1` 62mΩ // `Rsense2` 5.1mΩ -> `Rsense` 4.7112mΩ

Comment: In the schematic you show 4x FETs in a bridge configuration, yet on the prototype there are 8x.  How are they paralleled?

Comment: The Ccs cap appears to be too small for noise suppression,  I would add 10 Ohm in series with 470pF across it.  the tick noise is a unstable saturation relaxation oscillator with piezo noise.

Comment: The choice of FETs, drivers, filters and ESR at switching f is critical for stable operation when increasing above webBench limits and operating below 10% load. This requires current ramp compensation.

Comment: The bigger question is what is your phase margin? try a transient step load test from every step range. e.g. 10~20% 20~50% 50~90%, 1~2% or where ever there is a problem using injected pulsed current into a transistor active load. and measure under/overshoot and settling time. Or do a Bode plot at different load currents. Then determine a better compensation method.

Comment: and always measure with an AC coupled 50 Ohm coax and termination for V on transient scope capture. reducing Ron /4 also increase Cgs x 4 so adapt driver impedance which affects stability.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Ccs was 47pF. Do you mean "in parallel" with "470pF across it"? Phase margin and transiet step load test are terms I am not familiar with. I am too novice in the field of electronics.

Comment: 47pF// (470pF+10ohm)  parallel and lower ESR ceramic caps near driver

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 With lower ESR ceramic caps near driver, I guess that you mean components `Cin3...14` and `Cout1...15`, these are TDK CGA6M3X7S2A475K200AB. According to characterization sheet ESR @0.2Mhz ≅ 0.006 ESR/Ohm.

Comment: With a current sense shunt of 4.7 mΩ although 6mΩ is good, relatively speaking this needs to be re-examined when you add more shunt switches as I suggested above to filter sub-μs spikes that affects  feedback and shutdown on low current loads along with reducing the ramp rate and/or better reduce the PFM rate for stability of regulation.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 The suggestion to change `Ccs` to "47pF// (470pF+10ohm)" works. When you convert your comments to an answer, I will accept that answer. Note: Efficiency with single MOSFET is still better with 0.1A and 3.22A loads.

Comment: Gate losses and transition VI losses must be higher for reasons unproven yet. So what did you change and what was the effect?  Were the FETs matched?

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 The only difference between these boards is the population of M1_1, M2_2, M3_2 and M4_2: single MOSFET version, these 4 pads are empty, dual = filled with identical MOSFET: `M1_1=M1_2=M3_1=M3_2`=Infineon `BSC037N08NS5ATMA1`, `M2_1=M2_2`=Infineon `BSC190N15NS3GATM`, `M4_1=M4_2`=TI `CSD19531Q5AT`.

Comment: Do you have FET Diff probes to check signal integrity of Rcsp,Rcsg vias? under / over threshold of normal operation in light load? worst/best case Vin? as well as other critical information test points e.g. Cslope, Pgood

Comment: It seems you may need to change L1 or change slope or ?? to prevent low load ringing. eg SER2918H-103KL  . You did not post any load step results yet for various inputs and step loads for error, ring f and cycles. SMPS testing must be very through

Comment: Also load cables and reactance must be well designed.

Comment: Maybe you should change the MOSFETs to have a higher Rdson and lower gate charge, to work in parallel. I mean the equvalent gate charge could be to high.